# When will PostgreSQL 9.3 be supported on any version of Ubuntu LTS?

Tags: lts, postgresql, database

according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy-updates/database/ the latest version of PostgreSQL that's supported in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is 9.1, specifically the package name is postgresql-9.1 (9.1.13-0ubuntu0.13.10).

We'd like to know when would PostgreSQL 9.3 be available on on precise (12.04LTS) or the upcoming Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks

Shiva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres provides their own ubuntu-compatible repositories which can be found at http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/. This will allow you to use Postgres 9.3 on 12.04.

Trusty already includes 9.3.

Comment: This is by far the best option; for details, see http://apt.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 1):

Trusty will (or better: has since it is available already) have 9.3. [See the package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-client-9.3).

[image]

Regarding 12.04: 9.3 will probably not be backported so if you want 9.3 you probably need to find a PPA or source it yourself.